# WFFM 8.2 number field regular expression validation Message

Tags: wffm, validation

[image]

I am facing an issue with wffm number field regular expression.
Wherever a user enters alphabet characters in a number field it's showing default value "Field contains an invalid number." but i have entered regular expression field value in form editor(shown in screen shot). It should display message which I have given in Multi Regular Expression form editor. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

[image: Number field form editor Multi Regular Expression value[![Number field regular expression validation message showing default message]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYd0m.png)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario where you want to show regular expression message. Please use field type as Single-line-text and apply validation as "Number only" under validation section(left panel). Please see below screenshot of WFFM Form

**WFFM From**
[image]

**Page Response-** Here you can see in below screenshot,it is displaying regular expression message, now you can customize validation message.
[image]